# I need to add and additional condition to the html element as an attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, model-view-controller

I am using the ability to add conditional attributes to an html element in MVC. The problem is that I can only figure out how to add a single condition. currently the condition is as follows
If type of action drop Down contains OTA then show type of submission drop down
I need it to be
If type of action drop Down contains OTA then show type of submission drop down
else if type of action drop Down contains MOD then show modification drop down

I have been searching for answers and the only thing I am able to find is how I can utilizes JavaScript to get the desired result. I do not want to do this as I want to stick with the what has been used throughout the application.
The code I currently have is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginHalfSectionFor(x => 
    x.ItemActionDescriptionSection.TypeOfAction))
    {
        @Html.CustomDropDownListFor(
        x => x.ItemActionDescriptionSection.TypeOfAction, 
        ViewData["TypeOfActionDropDownList"],
        Model.ItemActionDescriptionSection.DisplaySectionAsReadOnly,
        new { 
            data_conditional_if_contains = "OTA", 
            data_conditional_then_show = "#typeOfSubmission" 
        })
    }
</div>
```

The desired result is if a user selects OTA from the type of action drop down then the type of submission drop down is displayed, if the user select mod from the type of action drop down then the modification drop down is displayed, if anything else is selected neither drop down is displayed.

Comment: Assuming I understood, the reason Javascript is being suggested is that it's likely the "best" solution to what you are trying to do. You seem to want to make changes to the DOM based on some user action (event). Of course you can _refresh_ the page with a server side call, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort it out, I had to use javascript and jQuery but its clean and works rather well. Here was my solution:
Using this script Im able to add attributes to the HTML element in the DOM that act as  conditional statements.
SCRIPT FILE

```
// Initializes a number of if-then logic rules throughout the form. 
function InitializeConditionalFormatting(targetArea) {
    $(targetArea).find("[data-conditional], [data-conditional-then-clear], [data-conditional-then-require], [data-conditional-then-show], [data-conditional-else-then-show]").change(function (event) {
    var target = $(this);
    // First, gets the value of the element that triggered the event when it changed. 
        var value;
        var elseValue = false;
        if (target.is("[type=checkbox]")) {
            // Can't get a value from a checkbox, so sets true if its checked and false otherwise. 
            value = target.is(":checked") ? "true" : "false";
        }
        else {
            value = target.val();
        }

        // Next, checks what test is being run, and if it succeeds or not. 
        var result = false;
        if (!result) {
            var ifEquals = target.attr("data-conditional-if-equals");
            if (ifEquals == value) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        if (!result) {
            var ifNotEquals = target.attr("data-conditional-if-notequals");
            if (ifNotEquals && !value.match(new RegExp(ifNotEquals, "i"))) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        if (!result) {
            var ifNull = target.attr("data-conditional-if-null");
            if (ifNull && !value) {
                result = true; 
            }
        }
        if (!result) {
            var ifNotNull = target.attr("data-conditional-if-notnull");
            if (ifNotNull && value) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        if (!result && !elseValue) {
            var ifContains = target.attr("data-conditional-if-contains");
            if (ifContains) {
                var text = (target.is("select")) ? target.find(":selected").text() : value;
                // For selects, where we're more interested in the selected option's text than it's value. 
                if (text.match(new RegExp(ifContains, "i"))) {
                    result = true;
                    elseValue = false
                }
            }
        }
        if (!elseValue && !result) {
            var elseifContains = target.attr("data-conditional-else-if-contains");
            if (elseifContains) {
                var text = (target.is("select")) ? target.find(":selected").text() : value;
                // For selects, where we're more interested in the selected option's text than it's value. 
                if (text.match(new RegExp(elseifContains, "i"))) {
                    elseValue = true;
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Finally, completes the corresponding 'then' actions based on the results (can be multiple). 
        var thenClear = target.attr("data-conditional-then-clear");
        if (result && thenClear) {
            ConditionalClear(thenClear); 
        }
        var thenNotClear = target.attr("data-conditional-then-notclear");
        if (!result && thenNotClear) {
            ConditionalClear(thenNotClear); 
        }
        var thenRequire = target.attr("data-conditional-then-require");
        if (thenRequire) {
            (result) ? $(thenRequire).rules("add", { required: true }) : $(thenRequire).rules("remove", "required");
        }
        var thenShow = target.attr("data-conditional-then-show");
        if (thenShow) {
            (result) ? $(thenShow).show() : $(thenShow).hide();
        }
        var thenShow = target.attr("data-conditional-control-to-clear-content");
        if (thenShow) {
            (result) ? NotClearContent(thenShow) : ClearContent(thenShow);
        }
        var elseThenShow = target.attr("data-conditional-else-then-show");
        if (elseThenShow) {
            (elseValue) ? $(elseThenShow).show() : $(elseThenShow).hide();
        }
        var elseThenShow = target.attr("data-conditional-control-to-clear-content");
        if (elseThenShow) {
            (elseValue) ? NotClearContent(elseThenShow) : ClearContent(elseThenShow);
        }
    }).change();

    function ConditionalClear(thenClear) {
        // This changes the target and triggers it's onChange method, be very careful of infinite loops. 
        if ($(thenClear).is("[type=checkbox]")) {
            $(thenClear).removeAttr("checked").change();
        }
        else {
            $(thenClear).val("");
        }
    }
}

function NotClearContent(e) {
    //nothing for now
}

function ClearContent(e) {
    //checkbox for now
    $("input[" + e + "]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is("[type=checkbox]")) {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked").change();
        }
        else {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });
}
```